# Character encoding in IDEA output of AssertionError

Tags: character-encoding, intellij-idea, testng, junit4

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4.
Have some tests. When i'm running one using JUnit4 framework my Assertion Error looks like:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status should be: Черновик expected [true] but found [false]
```

If i am using a TestNG it look like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status should be: Р§РµСЂРЅРѕРІРёРє expected [true] but found [false]
```

All other cyrillic outputs work fine on both framework, only assertion text won't.

Project files encoding set to UTF-8.

**Update:**
For example simple WebDriver test. I use TestNG and IE.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class SeleniumExample  {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected String baseUrl;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {

        /* Local Driver  */
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] TestData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"Гугл"},
        };
    }

    @Test(description = "Create_InvestProjectRequest", dataProvider = "TestData")
    public void Test(String s) {

        driver.get(baseUrl);

        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains(s), "Ошибка");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

In Test Result output i see:

java.lang.AssertionError: РћС€РёР±РєР° 
Expected :true
Actual   :false

And another problem that if i use cyrillic in DataProvider, then in Test tree i see Test("РћС€Р") instead of Test("Гугл")

Comment: OS/JDK versions/[encoding settings](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/)?

Comment: Windows 7 x86. jdk1.7.0_17. Encoding set to UTF-8. I try to force set VM encoding "-Dfile.encoding=CP1251" but nothing happened.

Comment: Please provide a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: @CrazyCoder add sample project to my first post

Comment: It looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59459 , but we were not able to reproduce it. Can you provide a complete standalone project that will show the problem?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Here you can download zip-file of my sample project: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30387490/AssertErrorSample.zip)
Inside there is main test class and TestNG lib file.
Run Example.class as TestNG test and look at the console output and test tree.

Comment: Add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the [.vmoptions file](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59459) that will be fixed in the next update, thanks for your project that helped us to trace it.

Current workaround is to edit the [.vmoptions file](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793) and add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` option.