# How to configure encoding for TestNG output in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: encoding, intellij-idea, log4j, testng

I'm runnig my tests on local environment using TestNG (6.8.8) plugin in IntelliJ IDEA (14.0.1) and got bad encoding of log generated by log4j:

```
[TestNG] Running:
C:\Users\user\.IdeaIC14\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml

INFO        com.common.reporter.ScreenShot#  33: РЈРґР°Р»СЏРµРј РІСЃРµ С„Р°Р№Р»С‹ РёР· РїР°РїРєРё C:\Workspace\tests\target\Custom suite\..\html\screenshots
TRACE       com.common.driver.DriverFactory# 137: os.name = windows 7
TRACE       com.common.driver.DriverFactory# 140: РўРёРї РћРЎ - windows
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e)) on port 20843
Only local connections are allowed.
```

I have tried configure VM options through Run/Debug Configurations and added options like described here - [Character encoding in IDEA output of AssertionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081657/character-encoding-in-idea-output-of-assertionerror) but both solutions did not help.

It works fine when running using mvn.

Any ides how could be this issue solved?